# Java Unique List

Tags: java, java-stream, distinct, hashset

I am currently trying to get a List with unique values.

Technically, it should be really simple, and the obvious choice would be a HashSet.
However, I want the properties of my "points" to be the uniqueness criteria and not their "IDs".

After that, I wanted to use the stream().distinct() method. Hoping that that one is using the overridden equals method. Sadly, this won't work either.

Any solution/Idea that works for double[] is welcome as well.

**PointType Class**

```
public class PointType{

private double x;
private double y;

public PointType(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other instanceof PointType && this.x == other.x && this.y==other.y){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I am aware of the flaw of double == double. For a minimum sample, it is sufficient.

Now to the issue:

```
@Test
public void testUniquness(){ 
   Set<PointType>setA = new HashSet<>();
   Set<PointType>setB = new HashSet<>();
   ArrayList<PointType> listA= new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<PointType> listB= new ArrayList<>();

   PointType p1 = new PointType(1.0,2.0);
   PointType p2 = new PointType(1.0,2.0);
   PointType p3 = new PointType(2.0,2.0);
   PointType p4 = new PointType(2.0,2.0);

// Trying to use the unique properties of a HashSet

   setA.add(p1);
   setA.add(p2);
   setA.add(p1);
   setA.add(p2);

   setB.add(p1);
   setB.add(p2);
   setB.add(p3);
   setB.add(p4);

//Now with array lists and streams.
   listA.add(p1);
   listA.add(p2);
   listA.add(p1);
   listA.add(p2);
   
   listA = (ArraList<PointType>) listA.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

   listB.add(p1);
   listB.add(p2);
   listB.add(p3);
   listB.add(p4);
   
   listB = (ArraList<PointType>) listB.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

   assertTrue(p1.equals(p2));     // Test passes
   assertTrue(p3.equals(p4));     // Test passes
   assertTrue(setA.size() == 2);  // Test passes (obviously)
   assertTrue(setB.size() == 2);  // Test failes. How can I use my custom equality condition?
   assertTrue(listA.size() == 2); // Test passes (obviously)
   assertTrue(listb.size() == 2); // Test failes. How can I use my custom equality condition?
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

For sure, a for loop would solve this too. But there has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: I think you should implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly in `PointType` in order to collect the unique ones by `stream().distinct()`…

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/1531124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue, your implementation of `equals` is not correct, this is what it should look like (auto-generated with IntelliJ) :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    PointType pointType = (PointType) o;
    return Double.compare(pointType.x, x) == 0 && Double.compare(pointType.y, y) == 0;
}
```

Second and most important problem, as the word `Hash` in `HashSet` suggests, you should not only implement `equals` but also `hashCode`, and this is not only true for hash collections but in general (every time you implement equals, you also implement hash code):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y);
}
```

Once you have done these two things, your test using `Set<PointType> setB = new HashSet<>()` will pass.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to override `equals()` together `hashCode()`. This requirement is reflected in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> **API Note:**
>
> It is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for
> the `hashCode` method, which states that **equal objects must have equal
> hash codes**.

You can find more information on how to implement `equals/hashCode` contract properly on SO, and in other sources, for instance, there's a separate item dedicated to this topic in *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch.

That how the correct implementation might look like (for conciseness I've used [Java 16 Pattern matching for instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html)):

```
public class PointType {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    
    public PointType(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        
        return other instanceof PointType o 
            && Double.compare(x, o.x) == 0 
            && Double.compare(y, o.y) == 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```